# Display Chinese using iTextSharp in Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, itext

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont("kaiu.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
```

I got error message "Encoding 1252 data could not be found. Make sure you have correct international codeset assembly installed and enabled."

I have this problem when I try to display Chinese using iTextSharp 5.5.10 in a Xamarin project.
I have tried for a while.
It really makes me confused.
Can anyone helps me to solve it. Very thankful.

Comment: Ian, please see the linked answer above on how to include code page 1252.

Comment: @matthewrdev thank you!! it's work well now.